# How can I making looping in two dictionary to multyple base on keys?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, loopingselector

```
price = {'Apple': 6, 'Avocado': 5, 'Banana': 3, 'Blackberries': 10, 
'Blueberries': 12, 'Cherries': 7, 'Date Fruit': 14, 'Grapes': 15, 'Guava': 8, 
'Jackfruit': 7, 'Kiwifruit': 9}

count_buy = {'Apple': 3, 'Blueberries': 4, 'Grapes': 1, 'Guava': 1, 'Jackfruit': 2}
```

this is my code:

```
def all_price(x,y):
   pass
   for i in y:
   multiple = x[i] * y[i]
   sum(multiple)
```

output:

```
103
```

I want to make multiple it in loops base on keys..
 multiple value base on keys
 then sum of all base on same keys

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve? Are you trying to get the total cost?

Comment: yes. done. i done

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
result = {key: price.get(key, 0) + count_buy.get(key, 0)
      for key in set(price) | set(count_buy)}
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the total cost, you can loop over the `count_buy` keys.

```
cost=[]
for key in count_buy.keys():
    price.append(count_buy[key]*price[key])

print(sum(cost))
```

Comment: oh, not like that.